# Is it possible to replicate Node.js scalability feature with single event thread, event loop and callback mechanism?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, scalability

Node.js solves scalability problem by running in a single, event-driven thread with event loop and callback mechanism. Visit this link for understanding the context of my problem : https://dzone.com/articles/quick-introduction-how-nodejs

Is it possible to replicate Node.js scalability feature with event loop + call back mechanism by using single event driven thread?

If this feature is possible with java, I will continue with java development otherwise, I have to chose Node.js for scalability my application - 120000 concurrent requests during peak hours

Comment: Java NIO, Java Swing, all are 'event' driven.

Comment: Any idea on why Node.js is  popular if Java can provide equivalent features?

Comment: That is unanswerable, it can range from people preferring javascript over java, to people not knowing that Java also provides this, to "hype"